# Print out an array list, and choose the index of one?

Tags: java, arraylist

`possibleRoutes` is of type `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Each of the array lists in `possibleRoutes` contains IDs of the tube or train stations connected to each other in the order of traveling.

```
for( ArrayList<Integer> route : possibleRoutes) {

        ArrayList<Double> routesDistances = new ArrayList<Double>(); // list of the total distances of the routes

        double distance = 0;

        for (int i=1; i < route.size()-1; i++){
            double x = Math.abs(stationLocations.get(route.get(i)).getX() - stationLocations.get(route.get(i-1)).getX());
            double y = Math.abs(stationLocations.get(route.get(i)).getY() - stationLocations.get(route.get(i-1)).getY());
            double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));

            distance += d;;
        }

        routesDistances.add(distance);

        System.out.print(routesDistances);

    }
```

This is the output so far:

```
[2163.9082950470897][3494.746239392733][2099.5269818921306][2075.3141294013]
```

I want to print out the list as an array list where I can choose an index from the list such as `routesDistances.get(0)` as for the first index. How do you do so that the list will be a type of `ArrayList<Double>` and be returned as:

```
[2163.9082950470897, 3494.746239392733, 2099.5269818921306, 2075.3141294013]
```

Comment: FYI, there's a `Math.hypot` function (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot(double,double)) to compute things like sqrt(x*x+y*y).

Comment: move `ArrayList<Double> routesDistances = new ArrayList<Double>();` outside the for loop

Comment: @IlyaBursov, the problem is the way he is printing should never print `[xxxx][xxxx]`: unless the `routesDistances` has size `1`. Ambiguous question.

Comment: @Sage in current code routesDistances has always size 1

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
ArrayList<Double> routesDistances = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

> before

```
for( ArrayList<Integer> route : possibleRoutes)
```

after the loop your **routesDistances** will like this:[2163.9082950470897, 3494.746239392733, 2099.5269818921306, 2075.3141294013]

and then the output in one loop just write like this:

```
for(Double d:routesDistances){
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> want to print out the list as an array list where I can choose an
>   index from the list such as routesDistances.get(0) as for the first
>   index.

As, @IlyaBursov has suggested, you could declare  `routesDistances` before the `for` loop.

And, to print from as specific index, you can use `subList(fstIndex, lstIndex)` function as follows:

```
 System.out.print(routesDistances.subList(index, aList.size()));
```